# How to extract the switching noise component for this signal data?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, signal, oscilloscope, instrumentation

A servo accelerometer when powered by batteries has a clean output, but when used with [this](https://www.tracopower.com/products/tmp.pdf) SMPS supply its output seems like have switching artifacts from the power supply(the datasheet says its switching freq is 100kHz). Now since the desired range is very low I can easily filter out such noise at the sensor output.

But having said that, I want to know what we can say about the noise at the accelerometer output. So by using a digital scope(at AC coupling mode) I made two measurements and logged the time series data for the standing accelerometer output. The first one is for longer period, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Then I plotted the time series and FFT of this as follows:

[image]

[image]

Then I did the same thing for a smaller time scale:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So by having all these information what can we say about the frequency of the switching noise? I'm trying to learn in such a situation how to quantify the switching noise. Should we look at the time series data or the spectrum for that? And for this particular case what steps should one follow?

**EDIT:**

For a much longer acquisition I observe the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**MEASURED DIRECTLY AT THE POWER SUPPLY OUTPUT:**

[image]

[image]

Closer view:

[image]

And spectrum:

### [image]

**Supply Output at 50us scale:**

[image]

Time series and FFT:

[image]

[image]

**The PSU noise(yellow) directly appears at the sensor output(blue):**

[image]

Comment: If that timebase is 250 nanoSeconds per division, then with 2 cycles per division you have 8MHz ringing. And some 2MHz (2 divisions period). To filter that, use 1uHenry and 1uFarad, which resonate at 160KHz, giving 100:1 attenuation to the 2MHz and another 16:1 attenuation to 8MHz..

Comment: Well just by judging the time between the pulses, they are not with a fixed frequency, there is quite noticeable jitter on it. And by counting the number of events over the time you plotted you get an average frequency of 15-16 kHz. So I'm not really convinced that it is the switching noise of 100 kHz doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your first scope plot correctly it's showing switching noise from a SMPS running just under 100KHz.  The apparent jitter is due to the fact that noise occurs on both edges of the switching waveform, so analysis of this waveform will show a fundamental at just under 200KHz, spread somewhat by the jitter on the switching edge.  You can see this nearly buried in the noise on your first frequency plot.

However, there's very little fundamental in this waveform.  Most of the energy is in the ringing, which you can see in the higher order spectral content.

Comment: How did you quantify the switching noise close to 100kHz? Between each spike I see like 50us to 60us that makes below 20kHz isnt it?

Comment: You're right, I misread the scale.  I'll give it some thought and come back with an edit.

Comment: Please also see my edit meanwhile.

Comment: I will also add info from directly supply output.

Comment: Can you post the supply output on a 50us scale?

Comment: I just added, see the last three plots screenshot, time series and FFT.

Comment: The switching noise looks like it's running at around 10KHz in the first (sensor) trace, but under 1KHz in the second.  The supply says it works at 100KHz (fixed), but that might be under full load.  It's possible that you're using so little current that it's in a power saving mode; other than the speed, the sensor trace and the power trace look pretty similar.  Can you hook up channel 2 and get a simultaneous output to test this theory?  You don't have to post it, just see if the spikes line up on both traces.  For further verification, you could hook up a resistor to draw more current.

Comment: The PSU noise(yellow) directly appears at the sensor output(blue): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOnOg.png

Comment: Well, it certainly shows good correlation.  I'd say that, due to your low current requirements, the supply is saving current by switching to a mode where instead of switching at full speed, it only kicks on when the output drops a few mV below its target.  That explains the various frequencies we see as well as the jitter.  In any case, I think it's safe to say your sensor output is being affected by the switching noise.  What kind of sensor are you using?

Comment: The sensors are servo-accelerometers. In LTspice I coulf filter this noise by using an LC filter with 1mH and 4700uF(or 10000uF). Do you think it is a good idea to post filter? I also tried to use a 12V regulator but it didnt help.

Comment: Post-filtering would help.  With some sensors, you can design the circuits to improve PSRR.  For instance, with electret microphones, almost all the noise appears across the element itself, and when you're stuck with a noisy supply you'll do a lot better measuring the voltage across the bias resistor rather than the mic element.  Another approach is to put an LDO after your switcher, trading a couple of volts for a reduction in noise (if you choose the LDO carefully).